# Is the security of this .net application flawed?

Tags: c#, .net, security

Ok, I know that every obfuscated **.Net application** can be reverse engineered.

And I know that it is better if I go the open source way if possible. But unfortunately I cannot because there is no copyright law to protect me where I live.

So I've come up with a plan to make it harder. Since I'm very very novice regarding the security I hope that you will help me find any loopholes in this plan.

1. The user downloads the application
2. The user enters his username/password and starts working
3. He need to export the results to a specific file format
4. The application connects to the server, and checks the username/password
5. The data required to create the file are sent to the server
6. The server creates the file on the server and sends it back to the user

Now if someone cracks the program by bypassing the username/password check the file won't be sent from the server and he won't be able to get the file he wants, something similar software as a service.

Now I want to know if this is the correct way to go? What suggestions to make it better?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one way to protect your IP is to hide parts of your application logic on a backend server where a cracker cannot simply remove simple piracy checks - they would need to reverse engineer your API to create their own service somewhere to keep the application working.

Note that while this makes things more difficult for crackers, it is not impossible to do, and there are several games who use this scheme that have successfully been "cracked".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can they reverse engineer it? They will need to know about structural designing and analyzing. Will they be able to do this without knowing these subjects?

Comment: It is a cumbersome process. The attacker will be able to view all requests his machine makes, and all the responses your server returns. Through this, it is not too difficult to try and recreate the logic stored on your server.

Comment: Thanks Martin, do you have any suggestions for me to protect it?

Comment: I think what you have at the moment is good enough. You never want to add more and more layers of anti-piracy to your app until it gets to the point of inconveniencing your paying users. You cannot worry about the few percent who will jump through hurdles to get software without paying.

Comment: Thanks Martin, don't you see any other flaws in this plan?

Comment: There is an incredible amount of bases you need to cover when you are trying to design a secure application. I suggest you keep asking on StackOverflow as you have more questions. For now, you're architecture is simple and effective - always a good start.